# How does Windows behave when you type an ALT code that is out of range?

Tags: c++, windows

I would like to display a wrong <kbd>ALT+xxx</kbd> code from the user's keyboard. In fact, I would like to reproduce the behavior of Windows when typing an ALT code which does not correspond to any character in the conversion tables.

I have no problem to display a correct code because the corresponding tables are available on the Internet.

For example, <kbd>ALT+065</kbd> gives `'A'` (easy), but <kbd>ALT+11111111</kbd> gives `'Ã'` on Windows, and I don't know what calculation to do to display that.

**LAST UPDATE** :
The answer is <kbd>ALT+xxx</kbd> % 256.

**EDIT** :

My code looks like this :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

void altCodeProcessing(char specialKeyCode[], int *specialKeyCodeSize);

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
     char altCode[5];
     int state, i, altCodeSize = 0;
     bool altGr;


    while (1)
    {
        for (i = FIRST_KEY; i <= LAST_KEY; i++)
        {
            state = GetKeyState(i);
            if (state != 0 && (state != 1 || i == VK_CAPITAL || i == VK_NUMLOCK))
            {
                 altGr = (specialsKeys[ALT].pressed + specialsKeys[CONTROL].pressed == 2) ? true : false;

                 //key processing
                 //ALT code processing

                 if (specialsKeys[ALT].pressed && !altGr)
                 {
                    if (i >= VK_NUMPAD0 && i <= VK_NUMPAD9)
                    {
                        //conditions to add and process to be implemented
                        altCode[altCodeSize] = j[0];
                        altCode[++altCodeSize] = '\0';
                    }
                }
                else if (altGr)
                    altCodeProcessing(altCode, &altCodeSize);

                if (altCodeSize)
                    altCodeProcessing(altCode, &altCodeSize);


                 //then log
            }
            
            Sleep(WAITING_TIME);
      }
}

void altCodeProcessing(char specialKeyCode[], int *specialKeyCodeSize)
{
    //make processing
    //Easy if the Alt code is right but what to do if the ALT code is wrong ?

    cout << specialKeyCode;
    specialKeyCode[0] = '\0';
    specialKeyCodeSize = 0;
}
```

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are asking. Could you provide some code showing what you are doing and where it goes wrong?

Comment: `ALT+11111111` is probably invalid or being truncated. Unicode doesn't have a code point with such a high value.

Comment: Interesting. It's rare that a question asks how to do something wrong.

Comment: @user4581301 Not only that, but the OP seems to have achieved his goal!  Anyway, OP, [mre] please.

Comment: I just shared a representative snippet of how my code is structured and what I'd like to do.

Comment: I still don't understand the question. What do you mean with "_if the ALT code is wrong_"? The number seems to be (from what I can gather from your question) the value of the unicode code point in decimal, except that `11111111` is out-of-range for that. I don't know whether Windows truncates the number of digits e.g. to four, but your code seems to have undefined behavior if more than four digits are entered. Is your question how Windows maps these key presses to a code point?

Comment: Yes, it is. I don't understand the behavior of Windows. I change the title and edit the question.

Comment: _I don't understand the behavior of Windows_ Believe me fella, you're not alone.

Comment: I don’t know what you are trying to achieve. Windows processes Alt codes for you. You do not need to do anything to get the character they represent. (I am unsure what you did to get Windows to give you the information to begin with.)

Comment: I suggest you look up what the Unicode point is for the character `'Ã'`. No doubt this will enlighten you as to what Windows did with all the 1s. If it doesn't, nothing else and nobody else can either, unless you can get a Windows developer here.

Comment: the default behavior is modulo 256, so Alt+11111111 is equivalent to Alt+199. [But a few apps can handle the Alt code themselves](https://superuser.com/a/1634718/241386), resulting in a different behavior

Comment: You can see the characters for DOS here  https://coding.tools/ascii-table and https://theasciicode.com.ar/

Comment: Huge thanks for your help, @phuclv gave me the answer I was looking for. I need to calculate ALT code modulo 256.